# Looping through column untill empty row, looking up each value in different SS and return row position

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to accomplish somewhat of a database table editor that edits rows based on a Trans ID.

I've accomplished vlookups and return values with a vlookup similar script I have, but this time I need to return position and not value.

I need help on how to set this script flow up. I've drawn and wrote everything out on a picture, it was a lot easier to write out that way.

[image: Diagram]

This is what I'm starting with and need some suggestions.

I want to return row position instead of value and repeat until hit first empty row as seen in example picture I attached.

```
    function vlookup(sheet, column, index, value) {                          
  var sheet = sheet
  var lastRow= sheet.getLastRow();
  var data=sheet.getRange(1,column,lastRow,column+index).getValues();

  for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
    if (data[i][0]==value){
      return data[i][index];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show what you've tried and explain why it didn't work. Limit the question to a specific programming problem instead of what you want to accomplish in the end.

Comment: i will edit the question.

Comment: Review how for -loops work and review arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The row number is just the index of the array + 1 as arrays start at 0.

```
return i + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the script on how I accomplished the task.

```
    function doit(){
 var lastrow = gv.glr(gv.invhelper,"A") // global function getting last row of target/loop column
 
 for (var i = 4; i < lastrow+1; i++){ //loop statement
 // actions to repeat
    var id = gv.invhelper.getRange("A"+i).getValue(); //get id from row 
     var duradj = gv.invhelper.getRange("D"+i).getValue(); //get billing adjustment from row 
      var dbidrow = gv.dblkup(id); // global function to lookup id  and find row position in other ss
       var invstat = gv.dbtimetest.getRange("G"+dbidrow).setValue('TRUE'); // set invoiced status
        var billadjust = gv.dbtimetest.getRange("M"+dbidrow).setValue(duradj); // set billing adjustment 
 }
}
```